# Error in parsing variable in multi variable function

Tags: r

I am getting error on var <- parse_expr(var) while creating summary for two variable, any body have any clue for this...??

```
dataa<-data.frame(
  aa = c("q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c","q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c"),
  col1=c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,2,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,2,5,3,5),
  col2=c(250,1100,100,750,400,100,200,700,500,700,200,600,200,200,600,300,400,300,200,500,700,500,600,400,400,600,500,600,400,100,700,300,200,700,700,200,300,700,200,400),
  col3= c(2150,3213,2580,4335,2228,3795,2319,2363,2252,3015,2978,2127,3938,3013,3063,4202,4340,4247,3755,4145,3300,3739,3294,2944,4152,2898,2500,3164,2384,2824,3431,2864,3752,2265,3332,3321,3418,3521,2689,2186)
)
```

Error : Error: x must be a character vector or an R connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. Part of the problem may be that your code is difficult to debug because your spacing and indentation make it very difficult to see what is going on. This is not a minor point of style or taste; it honestly makes a difference to how easy it is to write and maintain your code.

The problem that is actually causing the error is that your first function calls `rlang::parse_expr(var)`, but `var` is not a character string - it is actually a whole column from your data. When you call `tab_1d(tab,tab[i],var_name_list[i],Suff)`, you are passing `tab[i]`, which is a whole column from your data frame. You probably meant to pass `var_list[i]`.

The other big problem is with the parameters your functions include. Your first function includes two parameters that aren't actually used inside the function: `Name_of_variable` and `Suff`. Worse than that, when you call
`tab_1d(tab,tab[i],var_name_list[i],Suff)`, you are passing `Suff` as an unnamed variable, and `tab_1d` therefore thinks you are passing the character string `Suff` to `decimal`, so it can't interpret it properly.

It's a good idea when writing code in a functional language like R to identify repeated patterns in your code and see if you can create a function that prevents repetition of the code. This makes it a lot easier to see what's going on. For example, you could simplify your first function by first defining a little formatting function that allows you to specify your format more easily:

```r
format_quantile <- function(x, quantile, numdig) 
{
  quantile(x, type = 6, probs = quantile, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    round(numdig) %>%
    format(nsmall = numdig)
}
```

Now your main function can look like this:

```r
tab_1d <- function(dataset, var, numdig) {
  var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
  dataset %>% 
    filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>%   
    summarise(q25     = format_quantile(!!var, quantile = 0.25, numdig = numdig), 
              Median  = format_quantile(!!var, quantile = 0.5, numdig = numdig),
              Average = format(round(mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE), digits = numdig)),
              q75     = format_quantile(!!var, quantile = 0.75, numdig = numdig),
    N = sum(!is.na(!!var)))
}
```

You can also simplify your function that uses a loop to create a list by using `lapply`:

```r
tab_value_1d_row <- function(data, var_list, decimal) 
{
  tab <- as.data.frame(data[var_list])
  table_list <- lapply(var_list, function(i) tab_1d(tab, i, +decimal))
  Reduce(rbind, table_list) %>% flextable()
}
```

So now when you do

```r
tab_value_1d_row(data = dataa, var_list = c("col2", "col3"), decimal = TRUE)
```

You get:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, i have also tried like tab_1d(tab,names(tab[i]),var_name_list[i],Suff) , its also working like this change