# getting error while creating summary for quantile,average

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to calculate quantile and average mean but getting error

also its not grouping variable for "group_by(!!grp_var)" any idea what i am doing wrong

```
library(dplyr)

dat<-data.frame(
  aa = c("q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c","q","r","y","v","g","y","d","s","n","k","y","d","s","t","n","u","l","h","x","c"),
  col1=c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,3,4,2,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,4,2,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,4,4,4,1,2,5,3,5),
  col2=c(250,1100,100,750,400,100,200,700,500,700,200,600,200,200,600,300,400,300,200,500,700,500,600,400,400,600,500,600,400,100,700,300,200,700,700,200,300,700,200,400),
  col3= c(2150,3213,2580,4335,2228,3795,2319,2363,2252,3015,2978,2127,3938,3013,3063,4202,4340,4247,3755,4145,3300,3739,3294,2944,4152,2898,2500,3164,2384,2824,3431,2864,3752,2265,3332,3321,3418,3521,2689,2186)
) 

sam_table<-dataset %>% filter(!is.na(!!var),!is.na(!!grp_var)) %>%
    select(!! grp_var, !!var) %>% group_by(!!grp_var) %>% 
     summarise(
      q25 = format(round(quantile(!! var,  type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[2],digits = numdig),nsmall = 1),
      Median = format(round(quantile(!! var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[3],digits = numdig),nsmall = 1),
      Average = format(round( mean(!! var, na.rm=TRUE),digits = numdig),nsmall = 1),
      q75 = format(round(quantile(!! var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[4],digits = numdig) ,nsmall = 1),
      N = sum(!is.na(!!var)))

bygrps_table
#}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `ensym` rather than `enquo`:

```r
library(dplyr)

grp_var <- ensym(grp_var)
var     <- ensym(var)
numdig  <- as.numeric(decimal)
```

So the rest of your code should be pretty much the same (I've removed all the redundant `format(round(` calls for clarity)

```
dataset  %>% 
  filter(!is.na(!!var), !is.na(!!grp_var)) %>%
  select(!!grp_var, !!var) %>% 
  group_by(!!grp_var) %>% 
  summarise(q25     = quantile(!!var, 0.25, type = 6, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Median  = quantile(!!var, 0.5, type = 6, na.rm = TRUE),
            Average = mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE),
            q75     = quantile(!!var, 0.75, type = 6, na.rm = TRUE), 
            N       = sum(!is.na(!!var))) 
#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#>    P1      q25 Median Average   q75     N
#>    <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 c       400    450    450    500     2
#>  2 d       225    400    400    575     4
#>  3 g       400    400    400    400     2
#>  4 h       300    500    500    700     2
#>  5 k       100    400    400    700     2
#>  6 l       300    350    350    400     2
#>  7 n       425    550    550    675     4
#>  8 q       250    475    475    700     2
#>  9 r       500    800    800   1100     2
#> 10 s       200    400    425    675     4
#> 11 t       200    450    450    700     2
#> 12 u       200    250    250    300     2
#> 13 v       400    575    575    750     2
#> 14 x       200    200    200    200     2
#> 15 y       100    400    383.   625     6
```

You might also get a few useful tips from reading the answer to [this question with an awfully similar structure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390697/error-in-parsing-variable-in-multi-variable-function/63392969#63392969) Is this a class exercise?

---

**Data**

```r
dput(dat)
structure(list(aa = structure(c(8L, 9L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 
10L, 7L, 5L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 
9L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 
12L, 6L, 4L, 14L, 1L), .Label = c("c", "d", "g", "h", "k", "l", 
"n", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 
    5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
    1, 2, 5, 3, 5), col2 = c(250, 1100, 100, 750, 400, 100, 200, 
    700, 500, 700, 200, 600, 200, 200, 600, 300, 400, 300, 200, 
    500, 700, 500, 600, 400, 400, 600, 500, 600, 400, 100, 700, 
    300, 200, 700, 700, 200, 300, 700, 200, 400), col3 = c(2150, 
    3213, 2580, 4335, 2228, 3795, 2319, 2363, 2252, 3015, 2978, 
    2127, 3938, 3013, 3063, 4202, 4340, 4247, 3755, 4145, 3300, 
    3739, 3294, 2944, 4152, 2898, 2500, 3164, 2384, 2824, 3431, 
    2864, 3752, 2265, 3332, 3321, 3418, 3521, 2689, 2186), P1 = structure(c(8L, 
    9L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 
    7L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 
    10L, 7L, 5L, 15L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 4L, 14L, 1L), .Label = c("c", 
    "d", "g", "h", "k", "l", "n", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", 
    "x", "y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>